# Register type with no namespace in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://jquery-with-asp.net/2012/02/ajax-file-upload-with-asp-net-using-valums-script/).

But when I try to register the type as instructed in the web.config it does not work as I do not have a namespace in my website project.

His example

```
<add verb="POST" path="FilesUploader.html" type="FirstTestWebApp.FilesUploader"/>
```

My attempt

```
<add verb="POST" path="FilesUploader.html" type="FilesUploader"/>
```

His example

```
namespace FirstTestWebApp
{
    public partial class FileUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My Page

```
public partial class FileUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending global:: to the type name.  So type="global::FilesUploader" or whatever the name is.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't write namespace on top , it might be set at Project Level, check your project's property you'll find it named Default Namespace

Comment: Does a Website Project have a Default Namespace property?